# Why do data sets shows the old data when there is a change in the data source? Is there any permanent solutions to fix this?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report in production where it fetching ItemID from a particular DB. Recently we changed the data source but the report is still showing the old data. The only solution I could find was, re-create the dataset and refresh the field.

But every time we can't do this, Is there any permanent solution to this?

Comment: Check the caching settings on the report. Be default it should refresh the data every time the report is run.

Comment: Does use of a HAVING clause in the query creates this sort of issue?

Comment: No, HAVING is like a WHERE clause for grouped data. For instance `SELECT Product, COUNT(*) FROM Orders GROUP BY Product HAVING COUNT(*) >10` would show products where the order count for that product is more than 10.  Did you check the cache settings on the report on the server?

Comment: Yes, I did, It's been set to default. It refreshes for every 30 mins.

Comment: The default is to refresh each time the report is run. Try changing it to refrsh each time and see if that fixes the issue.